# Return an custom json with 1 object and 2 others values

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am using Spring with Jackson, and I need to return something like

```
{
"user": {
    "username":"myusername",
    "mail":"mymail"
    },
"custom": {
    "hasVoted":"true",
    "hasCommented":"false"
    }
}
```

Till today, I just send back an User object that is converted into jackson, but now I need to add a custom parameter. How can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Boolean> custom = new HashMap<>();
    custom.put("hasVoted", true);
    custom.put("hasCommented", false);
    test.put("user", User);
    test.put("custom", custom);
    return test;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I missspelled the title. It isn't 2 objects, it is 1 object and 2 differents boolean. Well, I guess that still works, Thanks !